# notebook heating up

Tags: cpu, cooling, toshiba-laptop, laptop

I have a toshiba m70-113 satellite pro laptop... its been five years since ive been using it..
[you can see its specs here...](http://eu.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/jsp/SUPPORTSECTION/discontinuedProductPage.do?service=EU&DISC_MODEL=0&ACTION=PRINT_WITH_BACK&com.broadvision.session.new=Yes&PRODUCT_ID=108831#0)

Its still does the job very well... the only prob is that it is getting heated up very quickly..

i have seen the cpu temp going up to 80degree Celsius!!
and HDD 60degrees celsius

I recently cleaned it up... but it did not help in lowering down its operating temperature... and the load is just normal load.. and not extensive... like browsing web.. etc..

One thing that i feel is that the fan is not effectively blowing up the air... and it has become very noisy too...

So i need to know what steps can i take to cool it... when it was new i definitely remember that it never got so HOT!..

please advise me steps to cool down my notebook as i have no plans to replace my lovable notebook...

Thanks.

Comment: 80 C is OK for the CPU but 60 C for the HDD is dangerously high and normally below 50 (mine is 42C)

Answer (score 1):

Aluminium notebook stand (not plastic as it's useless) will act as a heat sink. Get one with fans built into that, even better.

When you say you cleaned it, did you just blow out the vents or actually take it apart and give it a good cleanout with a can of compressed air? It might look clean but I've seen many a notebook in my time which was chock full of dust but looked new on the outside.

If the fans don't seem to be working you can try a squirt of lubricant on the bearings or otherwise just swap them out.